# How to replace posix alarm in windows

Tags: python, c, windows, multithreading, alarm

I am trying to create a program that will have a main thread which is just waiting for input, and some other threads. When the user inputs `freeze i`, thread number `i` should pause - freeze right away. Then, when the user inputs `continue i`, thread `i` will contine the thing it was doing. Each thread's (but the main one's) job is to print a message every x seconds.

The program should eventually be written in python, but a C solution, a pseudo-code, or even some ideas will help a lot!

For me, doing it in a POSIX OS is pretty easy: each thread (but the main one) will set handlers for `SIGALRM`, `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. It will also set `alarm(x)` and `while (1): pause()`. The `SIGALRM` handler will print the message and set `alarm(x)`. The `SIGUSR1` handler will pause the thread by setting `remaining_time = alarm(0)` and `pause()`. The `SIGUSR2` handler will continue the thread by setting `alarm(remaining_time)`. The main thread will send `SIGUSR1` when receiving the input `freeze i` and send `SIGUSR2` when receiving `continue i`.

But I can not find a way of doing this in windows. Please help me to find the right way of doing this! As I understand, it should be completly different from the way of doing it with POSIX, but I could not find the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 (recommended)**

In Windows, you just need to call [SuspendThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to pause a thread.  [ResumeThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
to wake it back up. **It does not get any easier than that.**

--

**Option 2**

I understand it correctly, the alarm/signal solution you have for your UNIX code is essentially to have each thread "self-suspend" upon getting notified by the main thread.

Instead of using alarm(), pause(), an signal() - use [SleepEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [QueueUserAPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) together.  Asynchronous Procedure calls aren't exactly the same thing as a signal in UNIX, but it is a  close equivalent and roughly matches your implementation as you have it now.

--

**Option 3**

Another solution is to just have a CRITICAL_SECTION lock associated with each thread.  The thread implementation would look something like this:

```
Thread:
while (true)
{
     Sleep(remaining_time_in_milliseconds);
     EnterCriticalSection(&cs); // enter lock
     printf("message\n");
     LeaveCriticalSection();    // exit lock
}
```

The the implementation of "freeze" and "continue" is to call EnterCriticalSection() - thereby blocking thread from continuing.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't get it to work yet.

Option 1: I'm still searching for a way to get a handle to the thread in python, as SuspendThread receives a handle. Also, MSDN says: "a thread within an application that is not a debugger should signal the other thread to suspend itself. The target thread must be designed to watch for this signal and respond appropriately". I'm not sure what they mean by signal. Still searching.

Comment: Options 2: You understand correctly :). But I don't really understand how these functions can help (see below).

Option 3: The are some problems, I think: The thread won't be paused in the middle of the Sleep. It will only pause at EnterCriticalSection. This way, it won't know how many seconds it still has to wait before printing. Example: x=10. 3 seconds have passed, and now the user calls freeze. The thread will remain sleeping and then wait at the lock. When the user calls continue, the thread will print the message immediately instead of waiting the remaining 7 seconds and then printing.

Comment: @user3356735 - use SleepEx with the alertable flag set to true. When SleepEx returns, check to see how much time is remaining and if the APC callback occurred. If the thread is signaled to be paused, you can SleepEx(INFINITE, true) until the wake-up APC has happened.  When you wake back up, you can decide how long to sleep for again.  Use GetTickCount() as a fast and accurate time function.